# global name cDate is not defined

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, lambda, apply

**this is what i put in do not know why it will not work? The error it returns is global name cDate is not defined

```
    dayv[['STRTTIME', 'ENDTIME']].apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: cDate(y,     '%H%M')))
-
NameError: ("global name 'cDate' is not defined", u'occurred at index STRTTIME')
```

Comment: which means that you have not defined `cDate` before using it. What exactly is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

`cTime` is part of the module `time` as said in the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html). So when it means that it is undefined, it is either not a variable, function, or anything in the code. You probably forgot to import `time`, which contains `ctime`. Try adding this to the beginning of your code:

```
from time import *
```

Replace the `*` with `ctime` if you are only using `ctime`. If you're fine using `time.ctime`, use this instead:

```
import time
```